# TypeError: Jest: a transform must export something

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

After configuring `jest`, `node.js` and `typescript` the script `npx jest` throws the error in a console

```
TypeError: Jest: a transform must export something.
    at C:\projects\project-api\node_modules\@jest\transform\build\ScriptTransformer.js:386:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ScriptTransformer.loadTransformers (C:\projects\project-api\node_modules\@jest\transform\build\ScriptTransformer.js:378:5)
    at async createScriptTransformer (C:\projects\project-api\node_modules\@jest\transform\build\ScriptTransformer.js:1105:3)
    at async C:\projects\project-api\node_modules\@jest\core\build\TestScheduler.js:283:31
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async TestScheduler.scheduleTests (C:\projects\project-api\node_modules\@jest\core\build\TestScheduler.js:276:5)
    at async runJest (C:\projects\project-api\node_modules\@jest\core\build\runJest.js:387:19)
    at async _run10000 (C:\projects\project-api\node_modules\@jest\core\build\cli\index.js:408:7)
```

jest.config.js

```
export default {
  roots: [
    '<rootDir>/src'
  ],
  testMatch: [
    '**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts)',
    '**/?(*.)+(test).+(ts)'
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts)$': 'ts-jest'
  }
}
```

Where did I fail to configure it correctly?

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by updating the `ts-jest` to the latest version (e.g. `yarn add ts-jest@next`). See [GitHub issue](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/2459)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had your same issue.

For me, it end up it was because I was having old version of following packages:

- ts-loader
- ts-jest
- ts-node

Comment: had a slightly different permutation of this answer, I didn't have `ts-loader` installed, installing it with `yarn add --dev ts-loader` solved it

Comment: if using npm then install it with `npm i ts-loader --save-dev` to avoid inconsistencies between package managers

Answer (score 10):

Running `yarn add ts-jest@next` solved it for me.

Comment: This answer is dependent on 'next' which will change over time. What version of ts-jest did you install?

Answer (score 10):

I tried to debug `Jest` by Node debugger (something like `node inspect test.js`) , and I found the culprit. For me it was `jest-svg-transformer` package. Apparently, it not compatible with `jest@27`.

Generally this error raises if some item in **transform** section of `jest.config.js` broken.

Comment: Also happened to me. Swapped it out for `jest-transform-stub`

Answer (score 6):

I had this error and it ended up being a miss-configuration in my `jest.config` (`transform`).

I had a property that should have been inside `moduleNameMapper` and not `transform`. Once I updated the file, jest executed correctly.

`jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/dist'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  verbose: true,
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|scss|less)$': '<rootDir>/test/styleMock.js',
  },
};
```

where `styleMock.js`:

```
module.exports = {};
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I had mismatched versions of jest (major version 26) and ts-jest (major version 27). Downgrading ts-jest to major version 26 solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

My fault was a custom transformer exporting a `process` function but not a default export, so I've got it working following `jest v27` documentation about it: https://jestjs.io/docs/next/code-transformation#typescript-with-type-checking

Answer (score 0):

If you upgraded from jest@28 to jest@29, you should change your transformer to return an object `{code:"foo"}` instead direct string `"foo"`

**jest@28**

```
process(sourceText, sourcePath, options) {
  return `foo+bar`;
}
```

**jest@29**

```
process(sourceText, sourcePath, options) {
  return {code: `foo + bar`};
}
```

Reference: https://jestjs.io/docs/28.x/upgrading-to-jest28%23transformer

[image]